# pandas data frame find all rows with particular column value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with column

```
 1445544152817 SEND_MSG  123
 1445544152817 SEND_MSG  123
 1445544152829 SEND_MSG  135
 1445544152829 SEND_MSG  135
 1445544152830 SEND_MSG  135
 1445544152830 GET_QUEUE 12
 1445544152830 SEND_MSG  136
 1445544152830 SEND_MSG  136
 1445544152892 GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE  26
```

I name the columns : timestamp type and response_time
 I do:

```
df = read_csv(output_path,names=header_row, sep=' ')
```

and its fine when I output the df it gives me all the values of the file.
Problem? When I do

```
df = df[df['type'] == 'SEND_MSG']
```

the df has 0 rows! How come? Its not true because the file and df have rows with type = SEND_MSG

here is my program :

```
warm_up = 100
cool_down = 100


def refine(df):
    start_time = np.min(df['timestamp'])
    #print start_time.columns[0]
    end_time = np.max(df['timestamp'])
    #print end_time.columns[0]
    new_start_time = start_time + (10 * 1000)
    #new_end_time = 0
    df = df[df['timestamp'] > new_start_time]
    #df = df[df['timestamp'] < new_end_time]
    return df


def ci(data):
    n, min_max, mean, var, skew, kurt = scipy.stats.describe(data)
    std = math.sqrt(var)
    error_margin = 1.96 * (std / np.sqrt(n))
    l, h = mean - error_margin, mean + error_margin
    return (l, h)


MSG_TYPE = {
    'SEND_MSG', 'GET_QUEUE', 'GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE'
}
COLORS = ['r','g','b']


def main():
    output_path = "/Users/ramapriyasridharan/Documents/SystemsLabExperiements/merged.txt"

    xlabel = "Time in minutes"
    ylabel = "Response time in ms"
    header_row = ['timestamp','type','response_time']
    df = read_csv(output_path,names=header_row, sep=' ')
    #df = refine(df)
    min_timestamp = np.min(df['timestamp'])




    df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'] - min_timestamp
    # convert time to minutes
    df['timestamp'] = np.round(df['timestamp'] / 60000)
    # filter all outlier above 70 seconds reponse times
    #df = df[df['response_time'] < 70 ]
    df['type'] = df['type']
    i = 0
    print df['type']
    for msg in MSG_TYPE:
        print msg
        df = df[df['type'] == msg]
        print len(df)
        response_mean = np.mean(df['response_time'])
        response_median = np.median(df['response_time'])
        response_std = np.std(df['response_time'])
        l,h = ci(df['response_time'])
        max_resp = np.max(df['response_time'])
        print "For msg_type = %s maximum response time %s"%(msg,max_resp)
        print "For msg_type = %s Response time avg = %.3f +- %.3f std = %.3f and Median = %.3f "%(msg,np.round(response_mean,3),np.round(h-response_mean,3),np.round(response_median,3),np.round(response_std,3))
        # round to nearest minute
        #find number of timestamps greater than 100
        #print df[df['response_time'] > 70]
        grp_by_timestamp_df = df.groupby('timestamp')
        mean_resp_per_min = grp_by_timestamp_df['response_time'].mean()
        #print mean_resp_per_min[0:36]
        plt.plot(mean_resp_per_min, 'x-', color=COLORS[i], label='%s requests'%msg, lw=0.5)
        i += 1

    response_mean = np.mean(df['response_time'])
    response_median = np.median(df['response_time'])
    response_std = np.std(df['response_time'])
    l,h = ci(df['response_time'])
    max_resp = np.max(df['response_time'])
    print "For msg_type = %s maximum response time %s"%('ALL',max_resp)
    print "For msg_type = %s Response time avg = %.3f +- %.3f std = %.3f and Median = %.3f "%('ALL',np.round(response_mean,3),np.round(h-response_mean,3),np.round(response_median,3),np.round(response_std,3))
    # round to nearest minute
    #find number of timestamps greater than 100
    #print df[df['response_time'] > 70]
    grp_by_timestamp_df = df.groupby('timestamp')
    mean_resp_per_min = grp_by_timestamp_df['response_time'].mean()
    #print mean_resp_per_min[0:36]

    plt.plot(mean_resp_per_min, 'x-', color='k', label='ALL requests', lw=0.5)
    plt.xlim(xmin=0.0,xmax=30)
    plt.ylim(ymin=0.0,ymax=20)
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    plt.legend(loc="best", fancybox=True, framealpha=0.5)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

    #print df['response_time']
```

EDIT: I found the problem,but have no solution

My actual data looks like what I pasted before ,but when I put it in a dataframe it looks like this, with spaces before the type

```
22059    GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE
22060    GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE
22061    GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE
22062    GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE
22063                GET_QUEUE
22064                GET_QUEUE
22065                GET_QUEUE
22066                GET_QUEUE
22067                GET_QUEUE
22068                GET_QUEUE
22069                GET_QUEUE
22070                GET_QUEUE
22071                GET_QUEUE
22072    GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE
22073    GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE
22074    GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE
22075    GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE
22076    GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE
22077    GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE
22078    GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE
22079    GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE
22080    GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE
22081    GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE
22082    GET_LATEST_MSG_DELETE
```

There is a leading space in front of get_queue, how do I solve that,this space is not present in my actual data

EDIT: The problem is the fact that type has varible size elements in it, how can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry in your first text block are you saying that your column has all that information: `1445544152817 SEND_MSG  123` this is not 3 columns? If so then it should be obvious why `df = df[df['type'] == 'SEND_MSG']` doesn't work, are you looking for `df = df[df['type'].str.contains('SEND_MSG')]`?

Comment: Can you check for trailing and leading spaces in 'type' column values?

Comment: @JohnGalt how do I do that? You mean visually?

Comment: @EdChum it says TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str', it doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry try `df = df.loc[df['type'].str.contains(['SEND_MSG'])]`

Comment: it says can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: @JohnGalt I think the df saves the second column with leading space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for just a single value (`SEND_MSG`) you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.columns = ['timestamp', 'type', 'response_time']
print df.loc[df['type'] == 'SEND_MSG']
```

Outputs:

```
       timestamp      type  response_time
0  1445544152817  SEND_MSG            123
1  1445544152829  SEND_MSG            135
2  1445544152829  SEND_MSG            135
3  1445544152830  SEND_MSG            135
5  1445544152830  SEND_MSG            136
6  1445544152830  SEND_MSG            136
```

The important line is:

```
df.loc[df['type'] == 'SEND_MSG']
```

Comment: it tells me that there are 5 columns and giving me an error when i assign headers the way you do, but visually i cna only see 3 columns, the space might not be uniform,is there a way to correct that?

Comment: I copied the dataframe you pasted into your original question, including the leading space before your first column. Prior to assigning the columns, do a `print df` and see what the dataframe looks like. If your `read_csv` is working, don't worry about the `read_clipboard` I have. Instead, adjust the `df = df[df['type'] == 'SEND_MSG']` line to the one I mention above